# initializing class as model inside BlocBuilder and getting error

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

in my application i have model as this below structure and i want to initializing that inside `BlocBuilder` to update ui elements such as `Text()`, for example:

```
class _Login extends State<Login> {
  UserInfo _userInfo = UserInfo();

  LoginListingBloc loginListingBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loginListingBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: loginListingBloc,
        builder: (BuildContext context, LoginListingStates state) {
          if (state is LoginUninitializedState) {
          } else if (state is LoginFetchedState) {
            _userInfo = state.userInfo;

            print(_userInfo.name);
          }
          return Text("My Username from server is: $_userInfo.name");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i don't want to make some variable such as `name`,`email` or `avatart` and fill them inside `BlocBuilder` to use them because i have this class model and i think i can initialize inside `BlocBuilder` to use that,

unfortunately i get this error when i run application:

> The following ArgumentError was thrown building
>   BlocBuilder(dirty,
>   dependencies: [MediaQuery], state:
>   _BlocBuilderBaseState#2342d): Invalid argument(s)

`LoginListingStates` class content:

```
abstract class LoginListingStates {}

class LoginUninitializedState extends LoginListingStates {}

class LoginFetchingState extends LoginListingStates {}

class LoginFetchedState extends LoginListingStates {
  final UserInfo userInfo;

  LoginFetchedState({this.userInfo}) : assert(userInfo != null);
}

class LoginErrorState extends LoginListingStates {}
```

and my `UserInfo` model class:

```
class UserInfo {
  String _name;
  String _email;
  String _avatar;

  UserInfo();

  UserInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : _name = json["name"],
        _email = json["email"],
        _avatar = json["avatar"],

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = _name;
    data['email'] = _email;
    data['avatar'] = _avatar;
    return data;
  }

  String get email => _email;

  String get name => _name;

  int get avatar=> _avatar;
}
```

Comment: i think you must init the blo inside build() function like this `block: BlocProvider.of<LoginListingBloc>(context);`, not in initState()

Comment: @Eugene now when i try to use `Text("My Username from server is: $_userInfo.name")` i get error `_BlocBuilderBaseState<LoginListingEvent, LoginListingStates>#e87e2):
Invalid argument(s)` problem is using `$_userInfo.name`